# rails with angular, 404 error video path to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, video, http-status-code-404, var

I am making a web-app with `ruby on rails`. I am currently seeking to add `angular` to my app. I made a separate simple angular app and I intend on merging both apps together. I found success in merging everything except for one video path. In the original angular app I found success by writing the code like:

```
   <script>
    var videoSource = "video/Background.mp4";
    var titleDisplay = "";
    var videoDescription = "caption";
   </script>
```

And in rails there are helpers like `video_tag` and `video_path` for example. 
I have tried many variations of writing this and have double checked the paths several times. The path for my video is `public/videos/Background.mp4`

I have also been trying variations like:

```
     <%= javascript_tag do -%>
      var videoSource src= "<%= video_tag("Background") %>";
```

but the only error continues to be

```
    GET http://localhost:3000/%7B%7BvideoSource%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your video is in a wrong directory. It should be under `/videos` directory.

From official documentation of `video_tag`:

> Returns an HTML video tag for the sources. If sources is a string, a single video tag will be returned. If sources is an array, a video tag with nested source tags for each source will be returned. The sources can be `full paths` or files that exists in your `public videos` directory.

Link to an official documentation of [video_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag)

```
video_tag("Background")
# => <video src="/videos/Background"></video>
video_tag("Background.mp4")
# => <video src="/videos/Background.mp4"></video>
```

Also, do not forget to add an `extension` part. As you can see from the above code, `video_tag` doesn't add it by default.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work, and I have read that documentation too, currently I have `var videoSource = '<%- video_tag("Background.mp4") -%>' ;` as far as wrong directory, it is in `public/videos/Background.mp4` are you saying it should not be and instead be `app/videos/Background.mp4`?